# Line chart with the number of tickets created by date

Tags: google-sheets

Here's what my sheet looks like: [image]

I'm trying to create a Line chart with 3 lines showing the number of tickets we get that labeled 1) billing, 2) info or 3) troubleshooting by date. So I want

- the date column on the x
- the number of times a date in the date column appears *with the same label in the label1 column* on the y

I tried making a pivot table and failed--it doesn't seem to be compatible with my date column.

I feel like the solution involves countifs but I can't wrap my head around what to do next.

Can anyone offer any insight or point me the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `query` formula can do things like this. Example:

```
=query(A2:B, "select todate(A), count(B) where B = 'info' group by todate(A) order by todate(A) asc")
```

This selects the dates (ignoring times) from column A for which there is at least one entry 'info' in B. The number of such entries is also returned.

If you want to also have 0 entered for the dates when no qualifying tickets were created, that can be done by applying the method of [Fill zeros for the dates when no data was recorded](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/92620) to the output of `query`.